# Trying to find items from one csv column not in another csv file (with multiple columns to cross reference)

Tags: python, csv

new to python and coding. Attempting to write a code that locates all of the items in 1 column from a csv file that are not present in another csv file (looking through 11 different columns).

**Addition:

1. I am starting with a data file of locations that have been assigned to part numbers. Each row has multiple "Bins" that have assigned locations.

   ```
                 Bin5        Bin6        Bin7        Bin8        Bin9  \
    0                                                                   
    1                                                                   
    2                                                                                                                                 
    ...           ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
    59995                                                               
    59996                                                               
    59997                                                               
          Aditional_Bin_Location  
    0                        NaN  
    1                        NaN  
    2                        NaN
   ```

The second document that I am processing is a master data list of all the available locations with important details associated to each location. I have a column named "Location Names", which I want to cross reference and remove all locations that have been found in the above "Binsx" column and export as a new document to have a list and description of known locations.

```
 Location_Name,Storage_Zone,EXP_AISLE ,Loc_Aisle,Storage_Area,Storage_Level,Loc_Velocity_Code,Storage_Type,Length_Inches,Width_Inches,Height_Inches,Storage_Wt_Cap
0            1A02A01,1,,1A,A01,A,Y,Small,23,5.5,7.75,188                                                                                                               
1           1A02A02,1,,1A,A02,A,Y,Medium,23,5.5,7.75,188                                                                                                               
2           1A02A03,1,,1A,A03,A,Y,Medium,23,5.5,7.75,188                                                                                                               
3           1A02A04,1,,1A,A04,A,Y,Medium,23,5.5,7.75,188                                                                                                               
4           1A02A05,1,,1A,A05,A,Y,Medium,23,5.5,7.75,188                                                                                                               
...                                                  ...                                                                                                               
53985        MGT U07C,TIER,,MG,7C,C,0,TIER- VARIABLE,,,,                                                                                                               
53986        MGT U07D,TIER,,MG,7D,D,0,TIER- VARIABLE,,,,                                                                                                               
53987        MGT U08A,TIER,,MG,8A,A,0,TIER- VARIABLE,,,,                                                                                                               
53988        MGT U08B,TIER,,MG,8B,B,0,TIER- VARIABLE,,,,                                                                                                               
53989        MGT U08C,TIER,,MG,8C,C,0,TIER- VARIABLE,,,,
```

I started a very basic code with the intention of looping it through each column (I can't figure out a way to do it better). I got the code to run but did not get anything close to what I expect (which would have been thousands of items that should be missing from the first column I check. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
empty_loc =[]

for Default_Bin_Location in full_locations.columns:
    for loc in full_locations[Default_Bin_Location]:
        found = 0
    if loc in loc_master["Location_Name"]:
        found = 1
    if found == 0:
        empty_loc.append(loc)

print(empty_loc)
```

I created a list and trying to build a if then statement to cross reference the master list (loc_master) to the first column in the assigned locations file (full_locations). I only pulled 3 results, which is impossible since I should have pulled closer to 8,000-9,000 locations that are actually "empty".

Any help would be wonderful, I have been struggling with this for about a week now and haven't made any progress. Thank you

Comment: Hi Nourah, welcome to StackOverflow. In order for people to help you, you should provide a fully working example. In this case, it would be easier if you can add in the sample code what is loc_master and full_locations, and which libraries you use for importing the csv file.

If you can provide code for generating a couple of sample csv files that the code can be tested with, the other users will be even more likely to help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, I have updated the information to help others understand better.